# Sum the two lowest values from a record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image]

I need to sum the two lowest values for each record. For example, in the first row 2 and 4 (2 + 4 = 6).

[image]

I can find the lowest value for each row using CROSS APPLY, but I can't find the two lowest values at once to sum them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Images are bad see [ascii table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select id, sumval - maxval
from t cross apply
     (select sum(val) as sumval, max(val) as maxval
      from values (value1), (value2), (value3)) v(val)
     ) v;
```

If you have three items, the sum of the smallest two is the sum of all of them minus the largest.

More generally, I would use something like this:

```
select id, sum2
from t cross apply
     (select sum(val) as sum2
      from (select top (2) val
            from values (value1), (value2), (value3) v(val)
            order by val asc
           ) v
     ) v
```

Comment: *"If you have three items, the sum of the largest two is the sum of all of them minus the smallest."* i believe it should be the sum minus the max..`sum( 2 + 4 + 5 ) = 11 minus max(5)` which is `6`.. when you do `sum( 2 + 4 + 5 ) = 11 minus min(2)` you get `9`  for the "first" record.. I also would choose the second query over the first assuming it is using MAX() as it is more clear and easy editable to allow more columns mine upvote is for the second query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . We are both right.  It is just that your interpretation is the question that is actually being asked.  I answered a slightly different question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 IIF (VALUE1 < VALUE3 AND VALUE2 < VALUE3, 
       VALUE1 + VALUE2,
       IIF(VALUE1 < VALUE2 AND VALUE3 < VALUE2, 
        VALUE1 + VALUE3, 
        IIF(VALUE3 < VALUE1 AND VALUE2 < VALUE1, 
         VALUE2 + VALUE3, 0)))
```

-- You will have to decide what to do if none of the conditions are met: I set the result to zero. This gets unwieldy if you add more columns

Comment: Since you have only 3 values and you need to sum the lowest they, you can invert the question and find the max value and then subtract it from the total sum.

Comment: *"This gets unwieldy if you add more columns "* unwieldy? terrible would be the more correct term as the would need at more filters per added column and a nested IIF per column very error prone

Answer (score 0):

Initial data:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Value1 INT, Value2 INT, Value3 INT);
INSERT INTO @Table (Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES
     (2,4,5)
    ,(3,7,2)
    ,(9,1,6)
;
```

The code:

```
SELECT a.ID,SUM(a.[Value]) AS [Sum]
FROM (
    SELECT p.ID,p.Value
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY p.ID ORDER BY p.Value ASC) AS [rn]
    FROM @Table t
    UNPIVOT(Value FOR Param IN ([Value1],[Value2],[Value3])) p
) a
WHERE a.rn <= 2 /*pick up only two lowest*/
GROUP BY a.ID
;
```